# Как поснимать checkbox

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Имеется Чек Бокс вот такого вида, как на него нажать, при помощи, Python + Selenium?

```
<input data-v-3719c1ac="" type="checkbox" testid="ns-chbox">
```

Comment: По Xpath не получается, пробовал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
checkbox1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@testid='ns-chbox']")
checkbox1.click()
```

Comment: Вы показываете элемент с атрибутом testid="bonuscard", а в ответе testid="ns-chbox". Почему разные атрибуты?

Comment: @AtachiShadow Поправил вопрос. Моя ошибочка не доглядел, не от тудого скопировал

Comment: Так а вопрос то решили? То есть вам про `.click()` нужно было узнать?

Comment: @AtachiShadow Да, вопрос решил. Всё работает как я хотел. Нет, не про click(), я про него знаю. Я просто не знал как обратиться к этому элементу. Потом сам додумал.

Comment: Отметьте тогда свой ответ как ответ))

Comment: @AtachiShadow Пытался, через 2 дня только можно ))

Answer (score 2):

Альтернативный, более лаконичный, и, кстати, быстрый способ нахождения этого элемента - это "by css selector":

```
checkbox = browser.find_by_css_selector("input[testid=ns-chbox]")
checkbox.click()
```

Comment: Почему CSS-селектор это "лаконичный путь"?

Comment: @AtachiShadow как правило CSS selectors получаются короче (к примеру, если сравним `[href^=test]` и `starts-with(@href, "test")`), но, я вовсе не против XPaths - по мне они просто немного over-used - часто начинающие девелоперы используют гигантские сгенерированные выражения, и вскоре удивляются, почему их выражения перестают работать или нестабильны.  В контексте этого вопроса, большого значения, что использовать, XPath or CSS, не имеет..

Comment: Вы не правильно сравнили свой CSS и свой XPath. Должно быть вот так - `[href^=test]` и `[@href="test"]`, что не особо то и отличается. Бегло поинтересовавшись этим вопросом, нашёл на АгнлСО аргумент что CSS-селектор хорош когда нужны простые адреса не имеющих отношений с текстом и при работе со старыми IE, в остальных случаях XPath

Comment: @AtachiShadow `^=` это "начинается с", для чего в XPath есть функция `starts-with()`. `$=`, например это "заканчивается с" - для чего в XPath 1.0 совсем нет функции. Когда дело касается текста, то да - XPath будет более полезен.

Comment: Да хорошо, я в CSS-селекторах ничего не знаю))) вот кстати нашёл страницу с аналогами CSS-селекторов в XPath, там есть и замена `$=`, пусть и не такая короткая. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XPath/CSS_Equivalents

Comment: Ну то есть вероятно я с вами соглашусь, что он проще в базовых запросах. Но так же XPath даёт больше возможностей, когда вы за рамки базы выходите)) Я хочу сказать, что для тех кому адрес понадобился раз-два - лучше CSS-селектор. Но тестировщику всё же лучше знать XPath)

Comment: @AtachiShadow я бы сказал, идеальная ситуация - это когда у инженера есть знание и того, и другого, а также слабых и сильных сторон того и другого :)

Comment: ))))) вот и пришли к консенсусу)

Comment: @AtachiShadow Можете тут помочь? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/921544/Как-спарсировать-ссылки-selenium-python

Comment: @alecxe Можете тут помочь? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/921544/Как-спарсировать-ссылки-selenium-python