# Как спарсировать ссылки Selenium + Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Есть Сайт: https://instamart.ru/auchan/produkty-pitaniia/molochnyie-produkty-iaitsa/moloko

Мне нужно спарсировать вот эти все товары, которые находятся находятся здесь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно получить результат вида:

Название:ссылка

```
import sys, os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

import time


system = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

path_to_chromedriver = str(system + "\\chromedriver.exe")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)


link = "https://instamart.ru/auchan/produkty-pitaniia/molochnyie-produkty-iaitsa/moloko" # <------------------ Сюда вставляем ссылку на сайт instamart.ru тот раздел, который хотим спарсить.

driver.get(link)
```

Comment: Так а в чём собственно проблема? Ну зашли вы на сайт, а дальше что, как вы элементы то ищете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно определиться с подходящим локатором для каждого блока с продуктом, а потом найти имя продукта и ссылку на продукт внутри каждого блока:

```
import os

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Ваш существующий код тут

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# ждем пока загрузиться лист с продуктами
wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "products"))
)

for product in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".products .product a.product__link"):
    product_name = product.find_element_by_css_selector(".product__title").text
    product_link = product.get_attribute("href")

    print(product_name, product_link)
```

Получим:

```
Молоко Простоквашино Отборное пастеризованное 3,4 - 4,5% 930 мл https://instamart.ru/auchan/moloko-prostokvashino-otbornoie-pastierizovannoie
Молоко Parmalat ультрапастеризованное 3,5% 1 л https://instamart.ru/auchan/moloko-parmalat-stierilizovannoie-3-5-percent
...
```